# Micro front apps communication using Event Bus

Tags: angular, web-component

I'm implementing a web application mico front end apss using Angular Web Elements (there could be other technologies involved as well).  I want to use an `event-bus` sort of mechanism for each micro app to communicate with each other.  The apps will be listening on the event-bus and then respond to events such as (user-logged-in) and so on.

Are there any technologies(native or third-party) I can use to achieve this event-bus approach.  Its sort of like `topics` but on the front-end.

Comment: [MDN documentation: Creating and triggering Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Event Target constructor? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget It's targetted to go native in Safari soon, and even then the polyfill as outlined in the MDN page is pretty small. Then your recent bus can work almost the same as your DOM events, which is a great way to reduce the cognitive load of your application!